# Downgrade PHP 5.4 -> 5.3 on CentOS 5.10

Tags: centos, php

Due to being in some dependency hell and some issues with PHP 5.4, we downgraded from PHP 5.4 -> 5.3.

Since doing so, a few of our web apps are acting strange.

E.g:

`# php index.php`

Results in:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in... on line 14`

Usually this indicates someone forgot to close some curly brackets or close off `<?php` or `{` or something - but I've checked that and doesn't appear to be any syntax problems. It was also working fine prior to the downgrade.

Any ideas?

After down-grade:

`[root@server ~]# php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 10 2013 22:12:52)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
[root@server ~]# rpm -qa | grep php
php53-common-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-mysql-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-xml-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-ldap-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php-pear-1.9.4-27.el5.remi
php53-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-imap-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-pdo-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-gd-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-process-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-cli-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-devel-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-mbstring-5.3.3-22.el5_10`

[Update/edit: even stranger - many of the PHP files are working fine if I call them from the command line but when I hit them via the browser/apache, they return nothing.]

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the PHP short tags littered through the various web applications. Turning `short_open_tag` back on in `php.ini` (which was overwritten by the down-grade) did the trick.